# jquery in zkoss http request

Tags: jquery, httprequest, zk

Hey maybe you can help find the problem in my function?
I want get from url info and post after textbox.

```
<window title="test" border="normal">
<vlayout>
<textbox w:onOK="httpGet()" xmlns:w="client"/>
    <textbox id="opa"/>
</vlayout>
<script><![CDATA[


function httpGet()
  {

    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      document.getElementById("opa").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281856/jquery-in-zkoss-http-request", true);
  }
]]></script>
</window>
```

Comment: What is not working? Is there an error message? What is the actual result? What is the expected result? On what domain is your app running? What domain are you trying to query?

Comment: expected result is text from ulr. I just do not get the error message I click execute but nothing happens.

Comment: On what domain is your app running? What domain are you trying to query?

Comment: nothing I just create. zul file and run it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based the informations you provided I think you ran into the **[Same-origin policy (SOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)**. In short it means that web browsers don't allow java script access to other pages for security reasons.

You're probably running a local development server. This is domain **localhost**. And your trying to access domain **stackoverflow.com**. As these are **different** domains SOP **doesn't allow access**.

What you can do is using your server side code to query the web page and then provide it to the client.